# Replaced cmos battery in OptiPlex 745, now just black screen - no option to reset BIOS

Tags: boot, bios, battery

One frustrating issue is that no one knows the key to hold down upon startup. Some say F2, some F12, some F10, and some the Delete Key. This is a specific machine OptiPlex 745. I don't understand why it is so difficult to find that info. I looked in the available .pdf user manual. If it's there, I missed it.

Most "how to do it" videos and text descriptions start with entering the BIOS. But I can't get that far. The monitor is plugged into the non-VGA port. I'll look for a VGA but I think it just has this other port and a serial port (along with USB's and ethernet).

Some help posts said the motherboard, ram, or other components went bad. That would be an amazing coincidence as everything worked before the cmos battery replacement.

Now it's a brick - and an old brick at that. I'm considering having a technician look at it, but I'm hesitant to pour more money into it rather than get another, newer, refurbished machine.

If you now what key I'm supposed to hold (Hold, not tap, right?) on startup and how soon the BIOS setting option should appear, please let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: [Apparently](http://support.feelpcs.com/pc-spec/Optiplex760/systemse.htm#wp1157779) the key is F12, but _"prompt can appear very quickly, so you must watch for it to display, and then press <F12>. If you press <F12> before you are prompted, this keystroke will be lost."_ If you don't get the Dell logo, I'd suggest removing the CMOS battery and trying again.

Comment: Most of the time you are limited to just entering the UEFI settings by using Advanced Startup. Another solution, of course is to have no boot device.

Comment: If the screen is just black, I do not know how you can proceed.  For my machines (not Dell) the manufacturer Support said to have the machine off, start and press the BIOS Key repeatedly until BIOS started.  I was able to reset and get going. Try this process on your machine, but a black screen will be difficult to work with.

Comment: @Peregrino69, on some PC's I've found that *first* holding the Fn key down, *then* pressing the Power button, and *keeping* that Fn key pressed until the screen shows BIOS (or Boot Order options) works. The important part is not letting up on that key. Also, some PC's will not enter BIOS if the drive is "dirty", i.e., has hiberfil.sys. Attempting to reboot Windows three times, while aborting early by holding power button for 10 seconds, can force a full reboot, leaving drive"clean".

Comment: F2 is definitely the “Enter BIOS” selection, and F12 is definitely the “Boot Menu” option. However, if nothing comes up on the screen no key combination is going to work. Start troubleshooting hardware. Coincidence or not, something is not right.